# Updating Kafka Offset Immediately

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am developing a Spring Boot app that reacts to messages pushed onto a Kafka queue.

The version is Spring Boot 2.0.5, Finchley.SR1.

The Kafka version is kafka_2.12-1.1.0

The issue I am facing is that *sometimes* when I restart the application it replays old messages. This doesn't always happen - the only pattern I have spotted is that it seems to be after a few days of inactivity (say on Monday morning, just after the weekend).

I stop and start the app multiple times during the day as part of the development and don't see the same issue, only sporadically. It isn't linked to errors in the application either, as all the processing is clean.

I have configured my Kafka listener to use MANUAL_IMMEDIATE acknowledgement, and call ack.acknowledge() at the end of the listener method.

My Spring property file looks as follows:

```
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: kafka:9092
    listener:
      ack-mode: MANUAL_IMMEDIATE
    consumer:
      enable-auto-commit: false
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      group-id: user-mgmt-app
```

My Listener class is defined as follows:

```
@org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener(topics = "aggregate-event-topic")
public void receive(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> cr, Acknowledgment ack) {

   ...
   ack.acknowledge();

}
```

I have one instance of the app running, so it's the leader in the consumer group each time.

I have used the Kafka tools to look at the offset for the consumer group, and one thing I've noticed is that when I breakpoint the app at the acknowledge step it's not updating the CURRENT-OFFSET, it only seems to update it once all messages have been processed.

`./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server kafka:9092 --group user-mgmt-app --describe`

My understanding from other posts was that MANUAL_IMMEDIATE would update the Kafka server straight away after calling acknowedge(), rather than at the end of the batch.

Is my understanding incorrect? If so is there anyway to get the functionality I want (such as setting the batch size to 1 on each read from the partition, which I'm guessing may have performance implications). If so, how do I do this (any help gratefully accepted!)

TIA

Comment: `enable-auto-commit` does that, the manual commit will be after all the processing (so you need to handle timeouts and rebalance for example).

Comment: I can't use MANUAL_IMMEDIATE if I set "enable_auto_commit=true" as the app doesn't start, and as I understand it "enable_auto_commit" only commits at the end of the batch? So I'm back to setting the "max-poll-records=1"?

Comment: autocommit in kafka is done before the processing but may vary depending on its configuration. Since you have `auto-offset-reset: earliest` every time you start the app it will read from the beginning (according to the retention size/time of your kafka server). Anyway the MANUAL_IMMEDIATE should commit  immediately, remember that the listener is invoked per record, to access the full batch you need to define the factory as batch, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/_reference.html#committing-offsets (scroll down)

Comment: I'm finding that MANUAL_IMMEDIATE doesn't update immediately, hence my question. If I set the poll-size to 1 then it's consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The issue I am facing is that sometimes when I restart the application it replays old messages. This doesn't always happen - the only pattern I have spotted is that it seems to be after a few days of inactivity (say on Monday morning, just after the weekend).

I am guessing you are not using a 2.0.0 broker, where the default retention for consumer offsets was increased from 24 hours to 7 days. Older brokers expire the offsets after only one day - classic problem if you don't have messages over the weekend.

See [Notable Changes in 2.0.0](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#upgrade_200_notable).

> KIP-186 increases the default offset retention time from 1 day to 7 days. This makes it less likely to "lose" offsets in an application that commits infrequently. It also increases the active set of offsets and therefore can increase memory usage on the broker. Note that the console consumer currently enables offset commit by default and can be the source of a large number of offsets which this change will now preserve for 7 days instead of 1. You can preserve the existing behavior by setting the broker config offsets.retention.minutes to 1440.

I am not sure why you are not seeing the offsets update via the command line tool. AckMode.RECORD will update the offset after each record. MANUAL_IMMEDIATE will update when you call `acknowledge()` as long as the Spring Kafka version is >= 1.3 (Boot 2.0.x will pull in Spring Kafka 2.0.x).

Comment: I just ran a test with `ack-mode=record` and I see the offset keeping up just fine in `kafka-consumer-groups ... --describe`.

Comment: Thanks Gary, that makes sense based on what I am seeing. You mention about not using a 2.0.0 broker - the jars under /kafka/libs are named kafka_2.12-1.1.0 so does that not mean I am using a late enough version? I have checked server.properties and it doesn't have a property of "offsets.retention.minutes" though so I will try adding it and seeing what happens. I'll run a few more tests as well with the command line tool just to be sure they aren't updating as I mentioned and will check the Spring Boot versions as you suggest,

Comment: The 2.12 is the Scala version; the 1.1.0 is the broker version. The latest broker version is 2.0.0 (with an increased default retention). If the property doesn't exist, a default value is used; see [the 1.1.0 docs](https://kafka.apache.org/11/documentation.html) and the defailt is 1440 minutes.

Comment: OK great, thanks for the info, I will try a later version.

Comment: Just updated to Kafka 2.0.0 and have explicitly set the "offsets.retention.minutes" property to 2 weeks (just to be sure!) and will see how it fares on Monday after the weekend. I checked the offsets again using the command line for MANUAL_IMMEDIATE and it seemed to update the offset only after the first message received (the subsequent messages kept pace with the offsets listed). When I changed it to RECORD (and of course removed the Acknowledge parameter in my listener code) it seemed 100% consistent so will switch to that method instead and see how it goes. Thanks again for your help Gary!

Comment: In case anyone was on the edge of their seat... I can confirm that after 4 days of Kafka running with no connected clients, as soon as I connected a consumer to it again I *did not* re-receive the messages that had already been read, so the "offsets.retention.minutes" change (and updated Kafka broker) has resolved that part of my issue.